# How to integrate a Wiener process that freezes at a determined time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I would like to calculate the expected variance of the average of a Wiener process from time $0$ to time $1$. The equation I believe I am trying to solve is:
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^1 W_t \, dt \right)^2 \right]
$$

My answer is:

$$
\frac{t^3}{3} \biggr|_0^1
$$

This matches the numbers I get in a Monte Carlo simulation I coded for what I am trying to do and the discrete time solution to this problem.

Now consider the case where the Wiener process "freezes" at time $s$ where $0<s<1$. At time $s$ the Wiener process value becomes fixed, wherever it is at that moment, and is essentially a horizontal line. More formally, I am solving for:

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^1 Q_t \, dt \right)^2 \right]
$$

where

$$
Q_{t} = W_{t}: t<s \\
Q_{t} = W_{s}: t>s
$$

How do I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: The integral of a Wiener process (or its square) with respect to time will be a random variable, not a fixed constant.  Did you mean to take the expectation of the integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Nate Eldredge already pointed out, the Wiener process is a stochastic process and so the integral of a function of a Wiener process is a random variable. Therefore, the equation

$$\int_0^1 W_t^2 \, dt = \frac{t^3}{3}$$

doesn't make sense at all from the mathematical point of view.

As far as I understand, you are simulating sample paths of the Brownian motion and calculating (numerically) the integral above. By the strong law of large numbers, the average of your results should equal (approximately)

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^1 W_t^2 \, dt \right)$$

where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation.

By definition, $W_t$ is normal distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t$. In particular, $$\mathbb{E}(W_t^2) = \text{var}(W_t) = t.$$

So, by applying Fubini's Theorem, we obtain

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^1 W_t^2 \, dt \right) = \int_0^1 \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_t^2)}_{t} \, dt = \int_0^1 t \, dt = \frac{t^2}{2} \bigg|_{t=0}^1$$

Now, if you freeze your process, i.e.

$$Q_t := \begin{cases} W_t & t \leq s \\ W_s & t>s \end{cases}$$

it's the easiest way to split up the integral:

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^1 Q_t^2 \, dt \right) &= \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^s W_t^2 \, dt + \int_s^1 W_s^2 \, dt \right) = \int_0^s t \, dt + \int_s^1 s \, dt \\ &= \frac{s^2}{2} + s \cdot (1-s) = s- \frac{s^2}{2} \end{align*}$$

Hopefully, I haven't misunderstood your purpose, since - as it seems - your simulations match with your calculations.

---

To calculate

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^1 Q_t \, dt \right)^2 \right]$$

it's again the best idea to split up the integral:

$$\int_0^1 Q_t \, dt = \int_0^s W_t \, dt + \int_s^1 W_s \, dt = \int_0^s W_t \, dt + (1-s) \cdot W_s$$

Consequently,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^1 Q_t \, dt \right)^2 \right] &= \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^s W_t \, dt \right)^2 \right] + 2 \mathbb{E} \left[ (1-s) \cdot W_s \cdot \int_0^s W_t \, dt\right] + \mathbb{E}[(1-s)^2 \cdot W_s^2] \end{align*}$$

You already know how to calculate the first addend and also the third one is no harm (note that $W_s \sim N(0,s)$). For the second one, use

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ W_s \cdot \int_0^s W_t \, dt \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^s W_t \cdot W_s \, dt \right] = \int_0^s \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(W_t \cdot W_s)}_{\min\{t,s\}=t} \, dt$$

Comment: You are right, I mistated the problem. The problem I would like to solve is E[(\int_0^1 W_{t} \ dt)^2)] and then the same thing for Q. I found this page here: http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=4&threadid=39502 that explains clearly how to do it for W. How do I do the same for Q? And should I edit my original question to reflect my intent? How does it work here?

Comment: @Jim I added some hints to my answer how to calculate the expression for $Q$. And yes, it would be quite helpful for other users if you restated your problem.

Comment: Dea @saz, how is it possible to get square from $$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^1 W_t \, dt \right)^2 \right] =\text{?}= \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_0^1 W_t^2 \, dt \right]$$ . I mean Jensen gives you inequality.

Comment: @Ievgenii Write $$\left( \int_0^1 W_t \, dt \right)^2 = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 W_t W_s \, ds \, dt$$ and use Fubini's theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I am stuck. is it equal to $1$? $$\mathbb{E} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (W_t-W_s+W_s) ds dt = \mathbb{E} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (W_t -W_s) W_s ds dt + \mathbb{E} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 W_s^2 ds dt = 0 + s \bigg|_{s=0}^1$$, and one more question, $\mathbb{E} (W_{2s} | \mathcal{F_s} ) = 0 ?$

Comment: @Ievgenii Note that $\mathbb{E}(W_{s} W_t) = s \wedge t$, so basically you have to determine $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (s \wedge t) \, ds \, dt.$$ And no, the conditional expectation does not equal $0$, but $W_s$.

Comment: Why not then $\mathbb{E} (W_{2S} | \mathcal{F_s}) = W_{2s}? $, does somehow the $2s$ affect calculations?And if no, so why?

Comment: @Ievgenii The identity $\mathbb{E}(W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = W_s$ holds for any $s \leq t$ and it follows from the fact that $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale. If you have any further questions on this topic, please open a new question.